# Two dicts from one dict's keys show no differences even if there are differences

Tags: python

I have two dicts `spec_copy` and `actual_specs` and want to compare values of these two for keys of `spec_copy` only.
This is what I'm trying -
`all(spec_copy[k] != actual_specs[k] for k in spec_copy.keys())`.
Upon debugging these are the key values of those two dicts. -

[image]

[image]

Clearly the version is different still the condition returns False. It should return True instead.

Comment: Are all pairs of values different? No, they aren't, only one is different. Therefore it correctly returns `False`. I think you meant to implement the logic "are all pairs of values *equal*".

Answer (score 4):

I think you meant to use

```
any(spec_copy[k] != actual_specs[k] for k in spec_copy.keys())
```